# Building custom theme based on another

Tags: themes, load

Since the first time I set a custom theme in Emacs and then later attempted to modify some faces, I learned how to do it dynamically with the currently loaded and enabled theme.

Now, I am finally trying to build a set of my "own" themes. But of course, I want to base them on other popular themes. And I am a bit perplexed.

What does it mean for a theme to be loaded? What does this exactly do?

```lisp
;; let's say my currently loaded theme is different
(load-theme 'zenburn :dont-ask :dont-enable)
```

And If I load a theme but don't enable it, can I still fetch all its faces and their attributes?

I want to do something like: `(custom-theme-set-faces 'my-dark-theme ...` but instead of listing all the faces and their attributes by hand, I want to get them from another theme (not currently enabled one), and only change selected faces.

Comment: Consider clarifying your question to say what part of the "doc-string" of `load-theme` is unclear to you.  `C-h f` aka `M-x describe-function`.  In terms of building your own, consider opening up the source code of your favorite theme and tweaking it to create a new one ... changing the name of the theme, creating a new file, etc.

Comment: As I said: it's unclear what it means to "enable theme". The docstring says: "Note that enabling THEME does not disable any other already-enabled themes", implying there can be multiple enabled themes. I don't know, this is confusing. How can there be multiple enabled themes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the great help from amazing Henrik Lissner (Doom Emacs author) and others, I have found answers to my questions:

- About multiple enabled themes. Why is it possible to enable multiple themes?

> If you have multiple themes active at the same time, you have multiple groups of faces active at once.
> e.g. Theme 1 sets the background of emacs to red. Theme 2 sets the color of bold text to blue. Theme 3 makes comments dark grey.

> Activate them all and you have a red background, blue bold text, and dark grey comments.
> Though, generally, folks don't design their themes to be modular.

- How to get faces for a loaded yet not enabled theme?

> I think you'd need to look into (enable-theme)

I checked the code and found that `(enable-theme)` does: `(get theme 'theme-settings)`. That however returns a lot of data that I needed to streamline a bit; After a bit of bike-shedding, I wrote this:

```lisp
(defun color-theme-get-faces (theme)
  "Get list of faces with their attributes of a given THEME.
If theme is not loaded, it loads it first"
  (let* ((theme (get theme 'theme-settings))
         (theme-settings (if theme theme
                           (progn
                             (load-theme theme :no-ask :no-enable)
                             (get theme 'theme-settings))))
         (extract-props (lambda (props)
                          "extracts face props based on display type"
                          (seq-reduce
                           (lambda (acc x)
                             (pcase-let ((`(((,disp-type ,disp-val)) ,face-props) x))
                               (if acc acc
                                 ;; prioritize graphic & color displays
                                 (cond ((eq disp-val 'graphic) face-props)
                                       ((eq disp-val 'color) face-props)
                                       ((eq disp-type 'min-colors) face-props)
                                       (t face-props)))))
                           props nil))))
    (seq-remove
     'null
     (seq-map
      (lambda (x)
        (pcase-let* ((`(,prop-type ,face _ . (,props)) x))
          (when (eq prop-type 'theme-face)
           (list face (funcall extract-props props)))))
      theme-settings))))
```

Comment: OK ... what is if the multiple themes define the same symbol differently instead of modular extending each other? Which theme 'wins"? Or does it then result in side-effects and hard to track problems?